# swap content in fixed container. skrollr

Tags: javascript, jquery, skrollr

Im trying to create a scroll driven slideshow using the js-lib skrollr.
I want a certain ul to get fixed once the scroll reach a certain positions. then i want its li's to keep scrolling while the ul stays fixes. anyone that can help here?

I have prepared some code here: jsfiddle.net/tfzLs414/

Reference case: http://www.vectorworks2015.net
(the images below the '#01'-texts.)